# Using a pair of Polymer Component twice in the same page doesnt work

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Im new to Polymer. Im using two different Polymer components that communicates with each other. I have to do it twice (2 x 2 components).

The following code uses just one pair of different components and it works:

```
<dom-bind id="dombind">
  <template is="dom-bind">

    <polymer-componentA id="polymercomponentA_1" 
        attribute="[[x]]" 
        attribute="[[x]]" 
        attribute="{{x}}">  
    </polymer-componentA>
    <polymer-componentB id="polymer-componentB_1"
        attribute="{{x}}"> 
    </polymer-componentB>

  </template>
</dom-bind>
```

But when I add other pair of components, it starts working bad. I think they use the same component (instead of being independent):

```
<dom-bind id="dombind">
  <template is="dom-bind">

    <polymer-componentA id="polymercomponentA_1" 
        attribute="[[x]]" 
        attribute="[[x]]" 
        attribute="{{x}}">  
    </polymer-componentA>
    <polymer-componentB id="polymer-componentB_1"
        attribute="{{x}}"> 
    </polymer-componentB>

  </template>
</dom-bind>

<dom-bind id="dombind">
  <template is="dom-bind">

    <polymer-componentA id="polymercomponentA_2" 
        attribute="[[x]]" 
        attribute="[[x]]" 
        attribute="{{x}}">  
    </polymer-componentA>
    <polymer-componentB id="polymer-componentB_2"
        attribute="{{x}}"> 
    </polymer-componentB>

  </template>
</dom-bind>
```

I know this is not done well, but I dont find good examples about this.
Whats the right way to use two polmyer components?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible to show in fiddle or what errors you are facing?

Comment: Its a big project, but I will try. I think the attributes are mixed between both components

Comment: Both are using the same attribute so it will reflect to other too if you change in one. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I see. I thought being different templates would make them independent. They have to be two pair of components completely independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you provide a function, Polymer calls the function once per element
>   instance.
>
> When initializing a property to an object or array value, use a
>   function to ensure that each element gets its own copy of the value,
>   rather than having an object or array shared across all instances of
>   the element.

Source: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/properties#configure-values

**Example**

```
 static get properties() {
    return {
      data: {
        type: Object,
        value: function() { return {}; }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null`.
I might try changing the name of the attributes

Comment: This solution finally worked. Thank you! there was other problem